# Parsing JSON from Typescript restores data members but not type: cannot call methods on result

Tags: json, typescript

When I parse the JSON-stringified result of an object p1 back into another object p2, the second object gets the data associated with the first object, but I cannot call any nethods on it. Using http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/ I tried the following:

```
class Person
{
    constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {
    }
    Age() { return this.age; }
}

// Create a person
var p: Person = new Person("One", 1);

// Create a second person from the JSON representation
// of the first (NOTE: assert it is of type Person!)
var p2: Person = <Person>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p));

document.writeln("Start");

document.writeln(p.name);  // OK: One
document.writeln(p.Age()); // OK: 1

document.writeln(p2.name); // OK: One
document.writeln(p2.age;   // OK: 1
document.writeln(p2.Age()); // ERROR: no method Age() on Object

document.writeln("End");
```

How do I parse the JSON data and get a proper Person object?

Comment: Your logic is dangerous.  I wouldn't recommend creating classes directly from serialized data (probably from the net).  There may be security concerns.  Better to serialize class state data and then reconstruct the class object (i.e. new) based on this state data.  If you do *any* checking on the deserialized data (which you always should do after deserializing data to make sure it is not tempered with), then there is really no reason for you to cast the object into a class.  New-ing one takes just as long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
// Create a person
var p: Person  = new Person("One", 1);

// JSON roundtrip
var p_fromjson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p))

// Hydrate it
var p2: Person = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Object.assign(p2, p_fromjson);

document.writeln(p2.Age()); // OK
```

Answer (score 17):

JSON is a representation of the data only, not any behaviour.

You could create a method on the object that accepts the JSON object and hydrates the data from it, but a JSON object cannot transfer the behaviour (methods etc) only the plain data.

```
class Person
{
    constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {
    }

    Age() { return this.age; }

    static fromJson(json: string) {
        var data = JSON.parse(json);
        return new Person(data.name, data.age);
    }
}

var p: Person = new Person("One", 53);
var jsonPerson = JSON.stringify(p);

var p2: Person = Person.fromJson(jsonPerson);

alert(p2.Age().toString());
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that type assertion is not the same as casting - it's something that can be confusing when you move to TS from another language.

Comment: Thank you both. I had implemented something like this (actually I read in an array, say a[], and then create my actual array doing `persons.push(new Person(a[i].name, a[i].age))` but it seems clumsy. What I was looking for is a way to 'retro-fit' the behavious. I don't know enough about Javascript, but I suspected something like assigning to the prototype (see, I don't know enough about Javascript ;-))

Comment: Putting the mapping into the class stops the logic leaking out into your program, which is cleaner - so `persons.push(Person.fromJson(a[i]));` would be cleaner than having the mapping inline.